# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bindToGraph')

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

This is my first implementation of StateMachineFragment.

Goal: Attempting to create a class for re-usable lambda state. This class can take a parameter and pass this as payload to Lambda and the lambda will execute the right query based on the payload.

Below is my POC code to 'classs-ify' the lambda and the call to statemachine.

```
from aws_cdk import (
    Duration,
    Stack,
    # aws_sqs as sqs,
    aws_stepfunctions as _stepfunctions,
    aws_stepfunctions as sfn,
    aws_stepfunctions_tasks as _stepfunctions_tasks,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
)
from constructs import Construct

class SubMachine(_stepfunctions.StateMachineFragment):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, *, jobTypeParam):
        super().__init__(parent, id)

        existingFunc = _lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, "ExistingLambdaFunc", function_arn="arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:958$#$#$#$:function:dummyFunction")

        lambda_invoked = _stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "someID", lambda_function=existingFunc)
        wait_10_seconds = _stepfunctions.Wait(self, "Wait for 10 seconds",
                                         time=_stepfunctions.WaitTime.duration(Duration.seconds(10))
                                         )

        self._start_state =  wait_10_seconds
        self._end_states = [lambda_invoked.end_states]

    def start_state(self):
        return self._start_state

    def end_states(self):
        return self._end_states

class StepfunctionsClasStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        test_lambda_1 = SubMachine(self, "SubMachine1", jobTypeParam="one")

        state_machine = _stepfunctions.StateMachine(self, "TestStateMachine",
                                                    definition=test_lambda_1,
                                                    # role=marketo_role
                                                    )
```

When I try and deploy this code, I get the following error:

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bindToGraph')
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: From what I could understand in the error log: it is state_machine = _stepfunctions.StateMachine(self, "TestStateMachine",
                                                    definition=test_lambda_1,...)

Comment: Your _end_states is a list of lists. Don't wrap `lambda_invoked.end_states` in a list - it's already a list.

Answer (score 0):

So adding @property above the def start_stat and the end_states solved the problem for me.